# angular Filtering table with dynamic columns ng-model not getting set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to create an app that will build the table columns and rows dynamically im stuck when I try to filter. It seems like the ng-model im trying to set is not getting set.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6ruo7mj/49/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.filter('test',function(){
 return function(input,other){
 console.log(other);
  console.log(input);
  return input;
 }
});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141228.150706", 
        "score": "0.45000", 
        "time": "0.02"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.022147", 
        "score": "0.56000", 
        "time": "6.00"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.022112", 
        "score": "0.56000", 
        "time": "3.00"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.021955", 
        "score": "0.55000", 
        "time": "3.00"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.021920", 
        "score": "0.49000", 
        "time": "10.00"
    }];
    $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in cols"><input ng-model="search[column]" placeholder="{{column}}" type="text"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows |filter:search">
      <td ng-repeat="column in cols ">{{row[column]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <pre>{{search | json}}</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing

```
$scope.search = {};
```

Try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/)

Full code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('test',function(){
    return function(input,other){
        console.log(other);
        console.log(input);
        return input;
    }
});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.search = {};        
    $scope.rows = [{
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141228.150706", 
        "score": "0.45000", 
        "time": "0.02"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.022147", 
        "score": "0.56000", 
        "time": "6.00"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.022112", 
        "score": "0.56000", 
        "time": "3.00"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.021955", 
        "score": "0.55000", 
        "time": "3.00"
    }, 
    {
        "branch": "default", 
        "comment": "", 
        "name": "20141226.021920", 
        "score": "0.49000", 
        "time": "10.00"
    }];
    $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="column in cols"><input ng-model="search[column]" placeholder="{{column}}" type="text"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows |filter:search">
                <td ng-repeat="column in cols ">{{row[column]}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <pre>{{search | json}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic search Demo](http://welcometolearntoday.blogspot.in/2015/03/search-from-list-using-angularjs.html)
Angularjs using to dynamic filter logic